# <img> src into the background-image of <div> using script

Tags: php, html, background-image

Hi I would like to give my clients who use a CMS for their website the ability to add their own background image. My CMS doesn't allow clients to edit the background-image directly so I would like to enable them to do it by using some php or other script. I would like them to be able to upload an img as normal (this image will be hidden from view on the webpage but will be visible in the CMS) and then use the script to take the img src and put it into the background-image:url('...');

Here is my code:

```
<div id="maincontentcontainer" style="background-image:url('...');background-size:100%;background-    attachment:fixed;">

<img src="..." alt=""/>
```

Looking forward to any answers, thanks!

Comment: You have several questions here. I have a feeling if you looked into each part separately, you'd be able to get pretty far on your own. IE: How do I upload an image using PHP, how do I set an img src using PHP... etc.

Comment: CSS `z-index` to display the `div` above the `img`.

Comment: Is it a wordpress based CMS cause if so you can use a plugin, I am sure Joomla would have a similar feature... These generally override the background and allow you to place your own

Answer (score 1):

The js part, as I assume that's what you're asking for, is quite simple. You'll have to make sure your CSS is there to make sure it's not visible though. Also assuming jQuery...

```
            var $image = $('.uploaded-image'),
                src = $image.attr('src');

            $image.remove();

            $('#maincontentcontainer').css('background-image', 'url('+src+')');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/61znv2a3/

Comment: Hi thanks for this, it seems to erase the image but does not insert the img url to the maincontentcontainer background-image. Any suggestions?